# How to make LWP to just continue instead of terminating when timeout happens?

Tags: perl, lwp-useragent

```
read timeout at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 426. at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/LWP/UserAgent.pm line 844
```

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 2):

LWP *does* continue on with the next statement on timeout. Specifically, it returns an HTTP::Response object with a 5xx error code.

```
>perl -MLWP -e"my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(timeout => 1); print $ua->get('http://...something really slow...')->as_string;"
500 read timeout
Content-Type: text/plain
Client-Date: Thu, 30 Jun 2011 06:35:11 GMT
Client-Warning: Internal response

read timeout at .../lib/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 433.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just continue what?

If you want to disable timing out, just call `->timeout(0)` on your user agent object.

To prevent the exception from ending your process, wrap the code in an `eval {}` block; see http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html.

But I'm curious to know how you are getting the exception you show; using LWP in the normal way will already catch that exception and return an error response, allowing your code to continue.  Show your code if you want help.

Comment: continue to run the next statement instread of just terminating.

Comment: Will LWP possibly hang there forever if set timeout to `0`?

Comment: what exactly does `no timeout` mean? As it can wait endlessly and thus hang forever...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when the request is sent and the response is being received, and then, the connection is interrupted in the middle of this process (your Internet connection goes down), LWP will return a `$response->code` of 200, and will have a `$response->content` equal to a partial download of the content you requested.  Then, if you retry, you will immediately get the **read timeout** error.

Of course, this only happens if the connection is lost at a very specific part of the process... but it happens.

I suggest that you verify if the content you received is complete and, if it's not, work around it before attempting your next connection.